# Losing my mind from jquery validate and knockout

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate, knockout.js

I have been trying to do this for months, and months, and months, and
months. And I am literally at the point of tears from trying to get Knockout to work for me.

I have posts dating back way last year trying to do this. I
just simply cannot get validation to work with knockout and asp.net
mvc.

If I put the `$.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#__frmAspect");` line in, I
get the validation, but then it does not obey the submit handler. If I
take that out, it obeys the submit handler, but it does not get any
validation.

This is my code - all of it. (I think)

## Main View

http://pastie.org/2016031

## Editor View

http://pastie.org/2016043

## View Model

http://pastie.org/2016045

## Controller and Model Binder

http://pastie.org/2016052

## Html Output

http://pastie.org/2016100

## HtmlTags class

http://pastie.org/2016107

## Helpers

http://pastie.org/2016111

I have been stuck on this for literally going on 8 months. Can anyone
please help me? All I want is to submit the data back to the server. I
don't want ajax, I don't want a callback. I don't want anything fancy.
I just want to send my `JSON` model back to the server after proper
client validation, and have it get the data. That is all I want. I do
not want to use the `$.ajax` method. I have reasons for why I want to do
it this way, and they are not relevant to the question.

### Response to RP Niemeyer

**Yes, that worked!!!!!!!!** oh my god. I owe you like ,the last 8 months
of my life. I want to send you a cheesecake smothered in raw calories
of taste and internets.

I feel like I could punch the screen from how frustrated this problem
made me. I'm sorry if the question sounded rude, but no where on the
internet have I seen this kind of thing. I'm sure any other developer
can understand the frustration of a problem that just does not seem to
have an answer.

I have no idea how you came to this conclusion and I don't understand
exactly why it worked.

I tried the same thing with an object-instanced view model (where the
view model was not its own object, but an instance of another object)
and it didn't work. In other words, if I do ..

```
var aspect = function () { 
  this.Id = ko.observable(); 
 // other variables, using ';' and 'this' keyword 
 this.Save = function() { 
   alert('We got to the save function'); 
 } 
} 

var viewModel = new aspect(); 
ko.applyBindings(viewModel, $("#__frmAspect")[0]); 
// attach the jquery unobtrusive validator 
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#__frmAspect"); 
// bind the submit handler to unobtrusive validation. 
$("#__frmAspect").data("validator").settings.submitHandler = 
viewModel.Save;
```

This approach did not work.
Can I bother you to explain to me what is different, and why? I am
completely lost.

Comment: I have not looked at all of the code but I think you need to add return true; to the end of the method: submitHandler: function () {
   viewModel.Save(); return true;
  }

Comment: It never even hits that part of the code. I can put an alert in there to run and it never even gets fired.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think that the issue is that the unobtrusive library will have already setup validation on the form, so you would actually need to go in and set the submitHandler like:

```
// attach the jquery unobtrusive validator
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#__frmAspect");

// bind the submit handler to unobtrusive validation.
$("#__frmAspect").data("validator").settings.submitHandler = viewModel.Save;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/V8MhG/

Comment: Yes, that did work. I responded to your post on the Knockout forums, but I will respond here just so you can get the credit and the points. I'm going to wait a few days so I can add a bounty to this and award you the points - because this has been driving me up the wall so much that I really think you deserve it for solving it.

Comment: I have updated my question with more information, if you feel like answering. I'm going to award you the points regardless. Thank you so much for this. I wish I understood how you figured it out.

Comment: I tried the most basic sample and it still worked: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/DNgeJ/.  Must be something else with the full version of your code.  I will work with you on the KO forums to figure it out.

Comment: As promised, I've set the bounty at 100 points and will award it in 24 hours when SO lets me. Thank you again for everything.